# Null Pointer Exception Error in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jlabel

So I wrote this code before without methods and parameter passing and it worked splendid!

But once I started making it more organized using methods and passing parameters, I'm running into Null Pointer Exception. Why am I getting such an error?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class test {

    private static JLabel label;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        initializeLabel();
        initializeFrame(label);
    }

    private static void initializeLabel(){
        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        label.setText("hi");

    }

    private static void initializeFrame(JLabel label){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's helpful to include the actual error message (since it will tell you exactly what's wrong).

Comment: don't create a new label in initializeLabel()

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this function:

```
private static void initializeLabel(){
    JLabel label = new JLabel(); // This creates a new variable named label
    label.setText("hi");
}
```

You're trying to intialize `this.label`, but you're just creating a new variable and assigning it. Change it to this:

```
private static void initializeLabel(){
    label = new JLabel(); // or this.label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 private static void initializeFrame(JLabel label){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(label);  <-- Here it might be throwing NPE because label is not initialized and is null.
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

You have not initialized global `label` variable that's why you are receiving NPE. Don't create new label in `initializeLabel()` method else initialize global variable in it. So it look something like this...

```
private static void initializeLabel(){
    label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("hi");
}
```

Also change `initializeFrame(JLabel label)` to `initializeFrame()`. No need to pass label as parameter in it as you have declared `label` in class' global scope.

```
private static void initializeFrame(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(label);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you initialize `label` inside a method so it's scope is only to your method `initializeLabel()`. You should make `label` a global variable and then do the initialization in you method, that way your whole program will have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Because in initializeLabel you create a new label, but you don't assign the reference to it to your static variable, but instead to a local variable that is lost after the method executes.

Change to:

```
private static void initializeLabel(){
    label = new JLabel();

    label.setText("hi");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
```

within `initializeLabel()`, that's a *new, local* variable, not the object-level one you think you're setting. The object-level one is therefore still set to its default value of null.

If you want to affect the object-level one, just set it thus:

```
label = new JLabel();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change line 15 to:

```
    label = new JLabel();
```

Otherwise you redefined label.

Answer (score 1):

Since your are parsing an uninitialized `JLabel` to your `initializeFrame(JLabel label)` method you are getting this exception.

Initialize `label`  before parsing to the `initializeFrame(JLabel label)` method.

```
initializeLabel();
label =  new JLabel("Your label Name ...");
initializeFrame(label);
```